# ftp client with async javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ftp, ftp-client

I'm writing in node.js and using async.js and ftp client modules.
I'm using **async.series** and that is a function in async.series:

```
    var client = new ftp();
client.on('ready', function () {
    for ( var i = 0  ; i < stage._sub_directories.length ; i++ ) {
        var path = get_absolute_path() + DIRECTORY_NAME_LESSONS + stage._name + "/" + DIRECTORY_NAME_STAGE + stage._sub_directories[i];
        var file = 'copy.' + stage._sub_directories[i] + get_xml_file_name();
        client.get(path + "/" + get_xml_file_name(), function (err, stream) {
            console.log('done');
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.once('close', function () {client.end();});
            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
            callback(null, true);
        });
    }
});
client.connect(config);
```

the `callback(null, true);` is for async module.
When it's run, its insert into `for` loop `stage._sub_directories.length` times,   and **then** insert to `client.get()` just one time (last time).
it's created one file and not more.
what is my problem? I should use another async control flow? or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written, it won't work, because you're calling an asynchronous function, `client.get`, inside a regular loop.

You should replace your regular `for` loop for the `async.eachSeries` method, since you're already using `async.js`. Try this:

```
client.on('ready', function () {
    async.eachSeries(stage._sub_directories, function (subDir, done) {
        var path = get_absolute_path() + DIRECTORY_NAME_LESSONS + stage._name + "/" + DIRECTORY_NAME_STAGE + subDir;
        var file = 'copy.' + subDir + get_xml_file_name();
        client.get(path + "/" + get_xml_file_name(), function (err, stream) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            console.log('done');
            stream.once('close', function () {client.end();});
            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
            done();
        });
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's honestly frustrating how much markup and discovery is needed to "workaround" these current popular FTP modules...I'm the author of  [FTPimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftpimp) which I wrote specifically to tackle this frustration. **For example**, you could do the same thing using ***only*** the ftpimp module:

```
ftp.connect(function () {
    stage._sub_directories.forEach(function (subDir) {
        var path = get_absolute_path() + DIRECTORY_NAME_LESSONS + stage._name + "/" + DIRECTORY_NAME_STAGE + subDir;
        var file = 'copy.' + subDir + get_xml_file_name();
        //save from -> to
        ftp.save([path + "/" + get_xml_file_name(), file], function (err, name) {
            console.log(err, name);
        });
    });
    //@see http://ftpimp.net/FTP.html#event:queueEmpty
    ftp.once('queueEmpty', function () {
        console.log('files saved');
        //do more stuff ...
        ftp.quit();
    });
});
```

Comment: ftp.quit() is causing an error => throw new Error('ftp.run > parameter 2 expected a callback function'); (index.js:501). It appears to require a callback function to be passed.